# Does Google Drive upload the entire file or only the delta for a minor change?

Tags: google-drive, upload, pdf

I have a big PDF file (about 50 MB) on my PC which is associated with Google Drive. If i make some changes to the file by adding some highlighting and notes, does Google Drive upload the entire 50 MB file again or only the delta?

Answer (score 1):

Google drive doesn't currently support delta updates. Dropbox does.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, in 2020, this is no longer the case